# Verification of exercise from Tao's Measure Theory and request for simpler examples

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

Consider the formula for the 'measure' (where $\#$ denotes cardinality) for some $E \subset \mathbb{R}^d$:
\begin{align*}
m(E) = \lim_{N\rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{N^d} \#\left(E \cap \frac{\mathbb{Z}^d}{N^d}\right)
\end{align*}
From an earlier exercise on page 5-6 of 'Introduction to Measure Theory' by Tao, it is shown that the following limit exists for any set which is atmost a finite union of boxes. The text asks to construct an example where the following limit does not exist. Here is my attempt:

Idea: Since terms of the sequence depend on the rational intersections, if there are lots of rationals of only certain denominators present it would create seperate subsequences.

Construction: Define(for $d=1$)
\begin{align*}
A = \bigcup^{\infty}_{k=1} \bigcup^{1\leq r \leq 2^k}_{r\equiv1(\text{mod}2)} \left\{\frac{r}{2^k}\right\}
\end{align*}
Then we have:
\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{N}\#(A\cap \frac{\mathbb{Z}}{N}) &= 0, N \not= 2^k\\
&= \frac{1}{2^k}*\frac{1}{2}*2^k =\frac{1}{2}, N = 2^k
\end{align*}
for any $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Hence the limit cannot exist. Is this correct?
Is there a shorter and simpler example?

Edit:
As pointed out by @vizietto, the proof is faulty; however I guess if I consider two seperate subsequences as $N=2^k,2m+1$ then it should be fine

Comment: Your proof is wrong. When $N = 6$, you have $1/2 = 3/6 \in A \cap N^{-1}\mathbb{Z} \neq \emptyset$. Note that there is a simpler description of $A$ : it is the set of dyadic numbers in $(0, 1)$.

Comment: Oh, I see the issue, I didn't account for the fact that relabels would show up... let me try to correct the error in an edit